# WPF Control size is not the same at runtime

Tags: wpf

I am creating a new WPF application with visual studio 2015 Community.
I put some buttons in visual studio XAML editor.
I can see in editor I have big buttons, with a big font But when i run project, i see standard  windows buttons.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

*** Edit ***

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">

        <MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" Name="video" Stretch="None" />

        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you please add your XAML?

Comment: see my edit. Thanks

Comment: Well there's nothing suspicious in your xaml. I pasted it to VS2013 and the button looks just as it has to. As far as I know, code behind isn't affect the form's look in the designer so either you omitted something important in the snippet or it is a VS bug. Do you want the buttons to be big or not?

Comment: there is a little box at the left bottom corner of the designer window. It shows current zoom %. Try to set it to 100%.

Comment: You are true ! This is the explanation. Thanks a lot